Extreme Points of Set of Signed Measures
Let $X\subseteq \Re_+$. Define $\mathcal{M}$ as the set of finite signed measures on $X$. We know that $\mathcal{M}$ is convex and compact wrt the weak*-topology.
What is the set of extreme points of $\mathcal{M}$? I was wondering whether they are still Dirac measures, as in the case of $\mathcal{P}(X)$; i.e., the set of (Borel) probability measures on $X$.

I don't understand "compact".  If $\mu$ is a finite signed measure, then so are $2\mu, 3\mu,4\mu,\cdots$.

You are right. As mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405005/compactness-of-signed-measure , I should have clarified that $||\mu||\leq A$, for some $A >0$.
